# Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"\" (type string) at path \"category\" because of \"BSONTypeError\

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mean, mern, atlas

I have the Cast to error in JSON response when Adding the Product Details in the & when adding category showing Error.

const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { ObjectId } = mongoose.Schema;

{

category: {
type: ObjectId,
ref: "Category",
},

};

Except category Every detail is adding in the mongodb table

Comment: Please format your code

Answer (score 0):

You should try mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId

```
@Prop({ type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId, ref: 'ExercisePlan' })
    category: string;
```

And if you are trying to aggregate with _id so you should try

```
$match: {
    category: new Types.ObjectId(inputId),
},
```